# Is it possible to detect IIS kernel mode caching from the client?

Tags: iis, cache

My company has software that has a critical bug associated with kernel mode caching. We have distributed a fix, but we want to be aware of who has not applied the fix.

I would like to know if it is possible to detect kernel mode caching when the only access you would have is the web. I have tried to determine this from the headers, but this may not work since IIS is caching it on the server side.

With kernel mode caching on or off, I get the same headers back.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:9272
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Mon, 05 Dec 2011 19:59:32 GMT
ETag:"56424ca4193cc1:0"
Last-Modified:Tue, 25 Oct 2011 18:13:26 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I read in another question that IIS will not start caching immediately, but it waits for a certain number of hits to the file to determine if it should be cached. So I used a script to download the file 10k times, but that made no change in the headers.

Is this possible using scripts, firebug, or any other client side solution?

Comment: Why would you be able to detect an in-memory cache on the client? Perhaps you could explain what you want to happen; k-mode caching might not be the right solution.

Comment: Incidentally - 2 hits in 10 seconds by default.

Comment: I probably should have been more clear. I've updated the question to explain that I need it without non-web access to the server.

Comment: No. Unless there's a specific problem you can demonstrate using requests/responses (i.e. infer from the problematic behaviour), you can't tell.

Comment: Also "without non-web access" - you mean, using only HTTP requests/responses, remotely?